# Error while compiling MonoDevelop 5.7

Tags: compilation, mono, makefile, monodevelop, pybinding

I'm trying to compile "MonoDevelop 5.7" with "PyBinding" but sends me an error.

I downloaded the code of Mono and MonoDevelop from GitHub and compile the Mono code did not give me any problems.

**./Configure command**

```
killer@killer-laptop:~/Downloads/monodevelop$ ./configure --select

Select the packages to include in the build for the profile 'default':

1. [X] main
2. [ ] extras/JavaBinding
3. [ ] extras/ValaBinding
4. [ ] extras/MonoDevelop.Database
5. [X] extras/PyBinding
6. [ ] extras/MonoDevelop.MeeGo

Enter the number of an add-in to enable/disable,
(q) quit, (c) clear all, (s) select all, or ENTER to continue:  

Configuring package: main
-------------------------
Configuration options: 
Running aclocal  ...
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Running automake --foreign  ...
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-compile-warnings --prefix=/usr/local ...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for mono... /usr/local/bin/mono
checking for gmcs... /usr/local/bin/gmcs
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for update-mime-database... /usr/bin/update-mime-database
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for UNMANAGED_DEPENDENCIES_MONO... yes
checking for mono... /usr/local/bin/mono
checking for dmcs... /usr/local/bin/dmcs
checking for GLIB_SHARP... yes
checking for GTK_SHARP... yes
checking for GLADE_SHARP... yes
checking for MONODOC... yes
checking for GNOME_SHARP... yes
checking for GNOME_VFS_SHARP... yes
checking for GCONF_SHARP... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating build/Makefile
config.status: creating build/MacOSX/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/Makefile
config.status: creating contrib/ICSharpCode.Decompiler/Makefile
config.status: creating external/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/Mono.Texteditor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/Makefile
config.status: creating src/core/MonoDevelop.TextEditor.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdhost/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdtool/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/SharpCoco/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/mdmonitor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDeveloperExtensions/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDeveloperExtensions/NUnit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/NUnit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/NUnit/NUnitRunner/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Unix/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Subversion.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VersionControl/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/Autotools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CSharpBinding/AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/ILAsmBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/VBNetBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/ChangeLogAddIn/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libsteticui/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Mono.TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/TextTransform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/MonoDevelop.TextTemplating/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/TextTemplating/Mono.TextTemplating.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Autotools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment.Linux/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Gettext/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.RegexToolkit/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/CBinding/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/GnomePlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MacPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsAPICodePack/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsAPICodePack/Core/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsAPICodePack/Shell/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/WindowsPlatform/WindowsPlatform/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/Xml/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Refactoring/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.AspNet/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.HexEditor/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.DocFood/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/Makefile
config.status: creating src/addins/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/UnitTests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/UserInterfaceTests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/TestRunner/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Ide.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/MacPlatform.Tests/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating monodevelop
config.status: creating mdtool
config.status: creating monodevelop.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop-core-addins.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop-core-mac-addins.pc
config.status: creating monodevelop.spec
config.status: creating po/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating theme-icons/Makefile
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-compile-warnings

Configuration summary

   * Installation prefix = /usr/local
   * Version = 5.7
   * Version Label = 5.7
   * Compat Version = 5.0
   * C# compiler = /usr/local/bin/dmcs
   * Mono class library development extensions: yes
   * Version control providers:
   *     Subversion (Unix): yes
   *     Git: yes
   * Platform bindings: GNOME 
   * Unit tests: no

Now type `make' to compile MonoDevelop
Configuring package: extras/PyBinding
-------------------------------------
Configuration options: 
Looking for required packages
Checking for package 'gtk-sharp-2.0'.. found.
Checking for package 'mono-addins'.. found.
Checking for package 'monodevelop'.. found.
Checking for package 'monodevelop-core-addins'.. found.

monodevelop-python has been configured with 
        prefix = /usr/local
        config = DEBUG

Configuration Summary
---------------------

MonoDevelop has been configured with 
    prefix = /usr/local
    profile = default

Packages included in the build:
    main
    extras/PyBinding
```

But when I use make sends me this error:

```
./PyBinding.Compiler/Python25Compiler.cs(30,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CodeGeneration' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/AttributeNodeBuilder.cs(30,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/AttributeNodeBuilder.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/ClassNodeBuilder.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/ClassNodeBuilder.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/FunctionNodeBuilder.cs(30,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/FunctionNodeBuilder.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/PackageNodeBuilder.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/PackageNodeBuilder.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/ProjectNodeBuilderExtension.cs(30,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/ProjectNodeBuilderExtension.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/CompilationUnitDataProvider.cs(38,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/DataProvider.cs(38,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/DataProvider.cs(39,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorCompletion.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorCompletion.cs(33,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorCompletion.cs(40,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorIndentation.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorIndentation.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorIndentation.cs(33,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(27,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(28,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonNode.cs(26,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(30,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(28,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(29,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParser.cs(26,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParser.cs(27,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParserInternal.cs(34,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParserInternal.cs(35,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonResolver.cs(26,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonResolver.cs(27,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Runtime/Python25Runtime.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CodeGeneration' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Runtime/Python26Runtime.cs(31,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CodeGeneration' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Runtime/Python27Runtime.cs(32,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CodeGeneration' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding/PythonLanguageBinding.cs(28,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding/PythonLanguageBinding.cs(29,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CodeGeneration' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding/PythonProject.cs(35,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CodeGeneration' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorCompletion.cs(370,34): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Dom' does not exist in the namespace `MonoDevelop.Projects'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(33,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `CompilationUnit' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(157,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DomType' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(35,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ParsedDocument' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(33,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IExpressionFinder' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(152,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ExpressionResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParser.cs(33,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `AbstractParser' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonResolver.cs(34,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IResolver' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/AttributeNodeBuilder.cs(58,24): error CS0115: `PyBinding.Gui.Navigation.AttributeNodeBuilder.BuildNode(MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ITreeBuilder, object, ref string, ref Gdk.Pixbuf, ref Gdk.Pixbuf)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/ClassNodeBuilder.cs(59,24): error CS0115: `PyBinding.Gui.Navigation.ClassNodeBuilder.BuildNode(MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ITreeBuilder, object, ref string, ref Gdk.Pixbuf, ref Gdk.Pixbuf)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/FunctionNodeBuilder.cs(62,24): error CS0115: `PyBinding.Gui.Navigation.FunctionNodeBuilder.BuildNode(MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ITreeBuilder, object, ref string, ref Gdk.Pixbuf, ref Gdk.Pixbuf)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/PackageNodeBuilder.cs(72,24): error CS0115: `PyBinding.Gui.Navigation.PackageNodeBuilder.BuildNode(MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ITreeBuilder, object, ref string, ref Gdk.Pixbuf, ref Gdk.Pixbuf)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
./PyBinding.Gui.Navigation/PackagesNodeBuilder.cs(59,24): error CS0115: `PyBinding.Gui.Navigation.PackagesNodeBuilder.BuildNode(MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Components.ITreeBuilder, object, ref string, ref Gdk.Pixbuf, ref Gdk.Pixbuf)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
./PyBinding.Gui/DataProvider.cs(49,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Ambience' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Gui/DataProvider.cs(50,8): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IMember' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Gui/DataProvider.cs(54,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Ambience' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Gui/DataProvider.cs(80,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Ambience' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Gui/DataProvider.cs(80,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IMember' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorCompletion.cs(72,39): error CS0115: `PyBinding.Gui.PythonEditorCompletion.HandleCodeCompletion(MonoDevelop.Ide.CodeCompletion.CodeCompletionContext, char)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorCompletion.cs(245,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DomRegion' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Gui/PythonEditorCompletion.cs(372,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `INode' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.PatternMatching' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonNode.cs(44,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DomRegion' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(35,8): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IBaseMember' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(46,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IBaseMember' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(78,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IType' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(103,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IField' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(121,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IMethod' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonCompilationUnit.cs(160,27): error CS0115: `PyBinding.Parser.Dom.PythonCompilationUnit.PackageDomType.StockIcon' is marked as an override but no suitable property found to override
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(182,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `DomRegion' could not be found. Are you missing `ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(311,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FoldingRegion' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(330,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FoldingRegion' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(361,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FoldingRegion' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser.Dom/PythonParsedDocument.cs(375,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FoldingRegion' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(43,8): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IExpressionFinder' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(48,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IExpressionFinder' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(61,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IExpressionFinder' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonExpressionFinder.cs(37,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProjectDom' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParser.cs(42,19): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ParsedDocument' could not be found. Are you missing `MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem' using directive?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParser.cs(63,19): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IResolver' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonParser.cs(68,19): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IExpressionFinder' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonResolver.cs(45,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IResolver' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonResolver.cs(36,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProjectDom' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonResolver.cs(39,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ProjectDom' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding.Parser/PythonResolver.cs(114,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MethodResolveResult' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding/PythonExecutionCommand.cs(34,26): error CS0115: `PyBinding.PythonExecutionCommand.CommandString' is marked as an override but no suitable property found to override
./PyBinding/PythonLanguageBinding.cs(53,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IParser' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding/PythonLanguageBinding.cs(61,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IRefactorer' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
./PyBinding/PythonProject.cs(45,26): warning CS0672: Member `PyBinding.PythonProject.ProjectType' overrides obsolete member `MonoDevelop.Projects.Project.ProjectType'. Add the Obsolete attribute to `PyBinding.PythonProject.ProjectType'
/home/killer/Downloads/monodevelop/main/build/bin/MonoDevelop.Core.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous warning)
Compilation failed: 86 error(s), 1 warnings
Makefile:164: recipe for target '../build/PyBinding.dll' failed
make[2]: *** [../build/PyBinding.dll] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/killer/Downloads/monodevelop/extras/PyBinding/PyBinding'
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/killer/Downloads/monodevelop/extras/PyBinding'
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

If anyone knows how to fix this error please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [PyBinding source code](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/extras/PyBinding) it has not been updated for MonoDevelop 5.0 and it is currently targeting MonoDevelop 4.2.3.

So it may be simpler to use an older version of MonoDevelop if you need the PyBinding to work.

Looking at the history for the PyBinding it seems that it is currently unmaintained and has not been updated for a few years.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only `main` and `extras/MonoDevelop.Database` options are allowed to use in build settings of monodevelop. Others options are not supported currently.